# Rails Controller Params - Custom Update Method for CanCan work around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm trying to limit access to a certain attribute when updating.

An admin is allowed to update all of a `Need` anytime they want, *except* they can only update the `Need`'s `is_public` bool only if `need_state` is `in_progress`.

CanCan doesn't allow a way to limit the update action based on specific attributes that are being set... so I thought they only way to accomplish this was to make a special method called `set_is_public`.

I've got my form calling to it and it's sending the following params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2u9AZ7AJDYQrXm3LubMAxlxhjbsQ14myUTyOSyvoKzk=",
 "need"=>{"id"=>"5",
 "is_public"=>"true"},
 "commit"=>"Set as Public"}
```

How do you go about updating that need in the action in the controller?
I can't figure out how to read those params in and:

- Find the need based on the id;
- Update its `is_public` attribute to the value of the `is_public` param.

Answer (score 1):

The params you posted show a nested hashed, so you should just need to do something like :

```
the_need = Need.find( params["need"]["id"] )
the_need.is_public = params["need"]["is_public"]
the_need.save
```

I hope that helps!

Edited to add : you may need to deal with parameter restrictions, depending on your version of Rails, one technique is a before filter that does :

```
params.require(:need).permit(:id, :is_public)
```

Please clarify your question if this is not helping

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I know it sounds so simple but this has caused me several hours of delay... It's showing: "Couldn't find Need without an ID" even though I can see in the params list that it is passing in: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2u9AZ7AJDYQrXm3LubMAxlxhjbsQ14myUTyOSyvoKzk=",
 "need"=>{"id"=>"5",
 "is_public"=>"true"},
 "commit"=>"Set as Public"}

Comment: enable debugger gem  "gem debugger" in gem file and call "debugger" method which will help you a lot when you're not able to figure out what is going on in the background.

Comment: Try: `params.require(:need).permit(:id, :is_public)`